# Compiler for actionscript 3 on Linux?

Tags: linux, actionscript-3, compiler-construction

I want to compile a tiny actionscript file. Is there something out there that exists and works?

I tried compiling and installing *swftools* without success. I also read about *Flex SDK* on all other posts. However all links are either broken or outdated. Seems like there isn't a package for Linux?

Comment: Have you tried this one: http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Setup+on+Linux? Rob

Comment: @Rob I started with it some hours ago and it is still downloading..

Comment: Apparently the snv repo is pretty big, but if you get the trunk only, it shouldn't be bigger than 500mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to compile and test out ActionScript is to use [Wonderfl](http://wonderfl.net/). It is a web-based Flash IDE that will compile ActionScript and allow you to view and download the resulting SWF.

To develop on your own machine, you can use the Flex SDK, which can be downloaded from [Adobe Open Source](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK). This includes `mxmlc`, the command-line ActionScript compiler. You can find more information on using `mxmlc` in the [Flex documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fcc.html). You could also try [FB4Linux](http://code.google.com/p/fb4linux/), a project that ports the Flash Builder IDE to Linux.

Comment: Wonderfl is awesome. Fast to the point! My only concern is that the generated .swf file is somehow bigger than other methods.

Answer (score 0):

checkout **redbean**

http://redtamarin.com/tools/redbean

it is a command line tool written in AS3 that reuse the asc.jar
to compile AS3 to ABC (ActionScript ByteCode)

download the redtamarin SDK

http://download.redtamarin.com/

it will gives you redshell, redbean, etc. for Linux

alternatively you can also install as3shebang
which will allow you to run AS3 as shell scripts

https://github.com/Corsaair/as3shebang